# bash: line 1: 9 killed /docker-entrypoint.sh cassandra -f and exited with code 137 on Windows 10

Tags: cassandra, docker-compose

Using docker-compose to compose the cassandra cluster on window 10, when docker service cassandra2 (sleep 60s) bootstrap the cassandra1 service will log error:

cassandra1 bash: line1: 9 Kllled      /docker-entrypoint.sh cassandra -f
cassandra1 exited with code 137

The details to link: 
https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/issues/107

Comment: Check the cassandra `system.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That the VM running the containers does not have enough memory. using "Docker for Windows" you can adjust the RAM slider in the settings.